# Merging multiple of summations into a single summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blKIi.png)

Hi guys can you guide me on how to do this question as I am lost just by looking at it

Comment: "*Hint: If you need, extract some elements from the sum and adjust the lower and upper limits accordingly*"  For instance, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{52}k=0+51+52+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{50} k$

Comment: Try getting each of the sums with the same lower and upper limits and use that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n b_k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (a_k+b_k)$